# Delphi and TIdTCPServer.OnExecute: How to correctly merge data

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

A very simple question I can't seem to find a definitive answer for.

I have a classic TCP Indy server. I send data in chunks. Each data packet is send in 1 or more chunks. When it arrives the OnExecute is triggered one or more times for each packet. More then one client can send data at any given time. How do I know which client / packet am I receiving data for in the OnExecute? I know its a trivial question probably but I want to have a definitive answer.

Comment: an example of one way to do it is here http://www.delphigeist.com/2010/09/custom-client-server-application-with.html, please note that it's a "rush" job and you can improve it a lot, but it's a start.

Comment: why do you send data in chunks? That's exactly what TCP does for you? You shouldn't have to care about these low-level issues.

Comment: If TCP does that for me I have the same problem. OnExecute is triggered more then once. Additionaly what if you are sending a very big file over. Will you just load it to ram in a single chunk. Not advisable. It is always good to separate data into managable chunks.

Comment: @Dorin, thanks will look at it. I just need a proof of concept, I will write the code myself.

Comment: @Smasher I don't agree with you, if you want to send big file, say 4 gb and the connection drops for whatever reason, do you start over, or continue from last successful packet?

Comment: @Runner the demo is sending data all at once(usually it's less than 1 MB), but you can easily modify it to fit your needs, it's a very basic start, hope it helps (:

Comment: @DorinDuminica that's why I asked for the reason...the question does not mention "4 gb" anywhere. For a 1MB file it's just overkill...

Comment: @Smasher it's true that 4 GB is not mentioned anywhere, but the same holds true for 100 MB, let's not assume that the customer has 100Mbps connection, and even if s/he has, how many users are expected to use that connection? While I agree that 1MB data sent in chunks **may** be an overkill, it really depends on the setup, also, sending in chunks allows pausing and resuming of data transfer, so there are many advantages... also, from my experience, requirements change a lot, so what may be an overkill now, may prove very useful in the future.

Comment: @Smasher, why is it an overkill. The chunk can be 1MB large so you have the same situation then. The data is send in one chunk, but if it is bigger it is send in more chunks. Who said the chunk has to be very small. All I see are advantages with such approach and no real disadvantages. You have basically no overhead if doing so, so your argument of an overkill is kind of void.

Comment: @Dorin, post your comment as answer it looks good to me.

Comment: @Runner awesome! I'm here to exchange knowledge not for the points, you can also answer your question and be more specific to the question.

Comment: Really, Runner? Although Dorin's comment answers Smasher's question of why we might wish to break a large TCP transmission into chunks, it doesn't address anything in *your* question at all, which asked how to sort out the chunks.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, look at the Dorins first comment, where he posted a link to a complete example. There I can see that I need to extend certain classes (context) to include additional info, such as client or data ID. I was reffering to that. I already answered Smasher with a comment before Dorin and then again in more detail. That has, as you figured out, nothing to do with my question at all. I just wanted to clarify to Smasher why breaking data to chunks is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can design the protocol, it could be done like this:

- the client starts with a initial command which includes total size and the chunk size
- the server OnExecute creates a temporary output file stream and stores file information in the context
- the client sends the chunks
- the server OnExecute reads chunks (using Indy TCP server blocking read methods with the known chunk length) and appends them to the output stream

The Indy TCP context class can be extended to add custom information for the client connection.

Comment: Ah it is the extended context class that I was missing. So then I can add client ID or the data ID to the context and this way I will know what to put back together on the other side. Not it seems clear to me.

Comment: @Runner the context class is on the server side only (see TIdCustomTCPServer). It is bound to the client connection (see TIdContext.Connection), and a subclass can be registered with TIdCustomTCPServer.ContextClass := TMyContextClass;

Comment: You can also use the `TIdContext.Data` property if you do not want to derive a new class.